# AngularJS custom ng-repeat with recursion not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The issue is best illustrated in the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/9DYQ3rlmiMK9bdtjyYOA.

Basically, I am trying to create a meta form rendering engine using angular with the help of directives that handle interpretation of data runtime and render the fields accordingly.

Please let me know if you have any ideas why the dyn-ng-repeat directive is not rendering the three URL fields under the user object as expected in the code below -

```
      <div dyn-ng-repeat="item in {{field.model}}">
          <div ng-repeat="field in field.children" ng-include src="'field.html'">/div>
      </div>
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Hi guys, I have created a full Plunker here - http://plnkr.co/edit/cFreJZbluy3w4R9PZUCD?p=preview that should have all the code necessary but not working.

Basically, there is a hierarchy of objects. Social Networks have URLS and a list of Friends. The code is supposed to display three social networks and each should have two friends listed under them. The button 'Add Network' should add another social network to the list and the button 'Remove Network' should remove the respective network associated with it along with all its children. Similarly, 'Add Friend' should add a new friend object under that Social Network and 'Remove Friend' should remove the respective friend from under that network.

It's a bit complex, but if you look at it for a couple of minutes, you'll get the idea of what I'm trying to do here. It's dynamic DOM based on the data elements that are bound two way.

Thanks.

Comment: why `element[0].removeAttribute('dyn-ng-repeat');` ???

Comment: That's just to remove the unnecessary attribute that gets replaced by ng-repeat. Commenting out that line won't change the behavior of the code.